# Best luks setup disk

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption, cipher-selection, luks, dm-crypt

I want to encrypt my disk but I want to know what is the best configuration, I currently use ths:

```
 cryptsetup -v --cipher serpent-xts-plain64 --key-size 512 --key-file=- --hash whirlpool --iter-time 10000 --use-random  luksFormat --type luks2 disk
```

Is there anything that can be improved?

Comment: You're supposed to use aes-xts not serpent on a device with AESNI instructions which means all non phone CPUs since 2010. Also see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Device_encryption#Encryption_options_for_LUKS_mode